# SQL Create new column(s) if row value exists

Tags: sql

I have a large data set that looks like the below:

```
NAME    Value
Dan     1 
Dan     92
Dan     A4
Steve   1
Steve   B10
John    4
```

I'm trying to convert it into a table like:

```
Name    Value1    Value2    Value3
Dan     1         92        B10
Steve   1         B10       Null
John    4         Null      Null
```

So there is an unknown amount of rows and I'd like to create a new column for every value when it exists. Anyone have an idea of how to do this in SQL?

Comment: please consider providing us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which will help the community in answering your question. In other words what have you tried so far and why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you provided would work perfectly using PIVOT, but you need to supply a category to the values to do the pivot.

e.g.

```
NAME    Category    Value
Dan     Value1      1 
Dan     Value2      92
Dan     Value3      A4
Steve   Value1      1
Steve   Value3      B10
John    Value1      4
```

Then your results would be like this

```
Name    Value1  Value2    Value3
Dan     1       92        A4
Steve   1       NULL      B10
John    4       NULL      NULL
```

Here's Microsoft's documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

To do this dynamically, please read this post. It handles the same situation well.
[SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Thanks and yes, I understand. However, the quantity of rows is unknown and varies wildly between 1 and 50. I was wondering if there was a way to somehow utilize a loop with a case statement

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a link on how to do this dynamically.

Comment: Hello FlogDonkey, the dynamic solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To pivot data you need something to pivot it by.

In this case it can be generated using ROW_NUMBER.

**For example:**

```
--
-- sample data
-- 
create table yourlargetable (
 id int identity(1,1) primary key,
 name nvarchar(30),
 value nvarchar(30)
);

insert into yourlargetable (name, value) values
('jane', 'val1'), ('jane', 'val2'), ('jane', 'val3'), 
('john', 'val4'), ('john', 'val5');

--
-- declare a few variables
--
declare @DynSql nvarchar(max);
declare @Cols nvarchar(max);
declare @ColTotal int;

--
-- how many columns are needed
-- 
select top 1 @ColTotal = count(*)
from yourlargetable
group by name 
order by count(*) desc;

--
-- generate a string with column names
--
with RCTE_NUMS as
(
  select 1 as n
  union all
  select n+1
  from RCTE_NUMS
  where n < @ColTotal
)
select @Cols = concat(@Cols+', ', quotename(concat('Value', n)))
from RCTE_NUMS
order by n;

--
-- create the dynamic sql string
-- 
set @DynSql = 'select *'+ char(10) +
'from ('+
'select name, value '+ char(10) +
', concat(''Value'', row_number() over (partition by name order by value)) col '+ char(10) +
'from yourlargetable) s'+ char(10) +
'pivot (max(value) '+ char(10) +
'for col in ('+ @Cols +')) p'+ char(10) +
'order by name';

-- select @DynSql;

--
-- run the dynamic sql
-- 
exec sp_executesql @DynSql;
```

**Returns:**

```
name    Value1  Value2  Value3
jane    val1    val2    val3
john    val4    val5    NULL
```